# Short story with an evil and vengeful alter ego of Jesus named Christobe

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I once read a short fantasy or sci fi story about the second coming of Jesus, but this time it was not the biblical Jesus who returns but an evil and vengeful one named Christobe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a number of works involving an Antichrist clone of Jesus. Do you know what they cloned him from? Did it result in an apocalypse a la Revelations?

Comment: Are you sure their name was not *Christobal*? That's a common name in some countries that is related to "Christ," whereas I have never heard of "Christobe."

Comment: I found precisely 1 fantasy work that contains the name "Christobe," "[The Shadow Watchers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95008)" by Dick Baldwin, but in the story Christobe is a demon/psychopomp, not an antichrist.

Comment: @DavidW - Thus why I imagine that Christobal, a much more common name with strong Christian relevance, might be what the OP is thinking of.

Comment: I could also see a possibility of it being Christophe, an even more common replacement, and b's and p's can get easily flipped for some people.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_Clone_Trilogy uses "Christopher" from the Shroud of Turin cells.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at either of the two current answers?

Answer (score 1):

Since we have another book series noted already, the *[Christ Clone Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_Clone_Trilogy)* (first book published in 1997, although a 2003 re-release seems more prominent) by James BeauSeigneur involves an evil Jesus clone who ushers in an apocalyptic Second Coming.

> The trilogy starts with *In His Image*, where living human cells discovered on the Turin shroud are used to clone a child, Christopher Goodman. The book follows Goodman's story by telling the tale of Decker Hawthorne, a journalist and the main character of the series. Among the main events covered in this book are the creation of Christopher, the rapture and Christopher's progress to becoming a key figure in the United Nations.
>
> The trilogy continues with the *Birth of an Age*, in which a series of disasters and plagues assault the earth and its inhabitants. Towards the end of this book, Christopher is killed and then resurrected.
>
> Finally in *Acts of God*, there is coverage of further natural disasters and the realization of Christopher's true identity and motives. This book follows through to the end of the world and life afterwards.

I read the series when it was being re-released in 2003 at my local library.

Answer (score 0):

*[The Brentford Chainstore Massacre](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/49608.The_Brentford_Chain_Store_Massacre)* (1997) by Robert Rankin, but more a novel as the fifth book in the *Brentford Trilogy* series.

> [As] the millennium comes early for Brentford, Dr. Steven Malone finds a way to clone Jesus from the Turin Shroud, as chief executive of the millennium committee called Fred (who sold his soul to the devil for ultimate power) attempts to force Pooley into sabotaging a ceremony that will give his Master power over all the world.

He names his cloned sons Cain and Abel.

Comment: Can you confirm that the name "Christobe" is used?

Comment: Haven't read it for a while, just rang a bell

Comment: It's not precisely a "replacement" of Jesus. Who' s coming  it's a real being but evil instead.

Comment: I read the story in spanish. Maybe the author is not engilsh or american. The name of the character was CRISTOBE